# MySql convert long unix to timestamp with miliseconds

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I have a table with timestamps that look like this: `1270237220080`

When I try to get convert it to `datetime`, it just gives me null values.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`) as mytime FROM table;
```

I think it is because the `UNIX timestamp` is saved with milliseconds instead of seconds.

Is there still a way to convert the time?

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 1000?

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp` / 1000) as mytime
FROM table;
```